# Is native like performance in a phonegap app too much to expect?

Tags: cordova

I am constantly looking for a combination of libraries to create a phonegap app which is as slick as a native app on iphone and android. I have yet to discover the perfect combination, am i expecting too much from phonegap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never achieve native performance on PhoneGap as there is always the WebKit layer between your code and the operating system. If could write really great JS code, you can definitely achieve good performance(again not comparable to native performance). Most of the UI libraries  like jQuery Mobile, Kendo UI Mobile etc. works well o iOS but not that great on Android, especially on 2.x versions.